# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Brightness Problem

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, brightness

Yesterday I downloaded Ubuntu and installed it on my laptop (Sony Vaio PCG-71811M), with Windows 8.1 dual boot. I really liked Ubuntu, and i don't think I want to delete Ubuntu and turn back Windows. But I deleted it because when trying to fix its brightness problem (low-screen mode).

Some outputs:

```
ls /sys/class/backlight/
```

It just says

```
acpi_video0.
```

Not like intel_backlight or something.

PC:

- Intel Core i5-2450M 2.50 GHz
- 4 GB RAM
- GeForce 410M- in UBUNTU: GF119M

And some codes:

```
~$ lspci | egrep "VGA|3D|Display"

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 410M] (rev a1)
```

---

```
~$ glxinfo | grep render

direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 410M/PCIe/SSE2
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering,
```

---

```
~$ lspci


00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 410M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
0d:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

---

```
~$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

---

Comment: It must be me, but what is exactly the problem? Too bright or too dimmed?

Comment: Can't change brightness. And it's too bright, i can't look at the screen.

Comment: Not just you. I'm not understanding either. I know on my wife's viao (model number very close, but I don't think it was nvidia) the fn + brightness up/down keys worked to adjust brightness. -- edit: okay too bright.

Comment: It works, but it doesn't change the brightness. Only shows up a bar and when I FN+F5 or FN+F6 bar is working but doesn't do anything. And I tried that solution, it didn't worked :(

Comment: If a workaround is needed, does one of these answers work for you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/583863/is-there-any-brightness-control-for-desktops/583873#583873

Comment: Are you using open-source or proprietary nvidia driver's from drivers section, or possibly nvidia xorg-edgers ppa

Comment: @JacobVlijm I tried that long time ago and it didn't worked. Geoffmcc- Using Nvidia 311 tested driver.

Comment: ??? how did you get that script? It's here since two days.

Comment: Which script ? Sorry, im new to these things :(

Comment: This one: http://askubuntu.com/a/583873/72216 you can test if the script should work (I can't imagine it doesn't) by the command: `xrandr --output LVDS-0 --brightness 0.6`. If that works, the script should as well.

Comment: Okay, i will give it a try. And, can you wait 20 min ? When I asked this question, I tried a solution again and get a low screen again :( Reinstalling ubuntu right now.

Comment: @Ceroder sure! I will be out for about an hour and will take a look immediately after :)

Comment: Okay, I tried to write "xrandr --output LVDS-0 --brightness 0.6" code to Terminal, but it gave me an error.

warning: output LVDS-0 not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on.

Comment: Are you using the same screen (looking at xrandr)

Comment: Same screen ? Yeah, xrandr is still same as the question.

"Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
"

Comment: Whoa, it worked ! But it just doing black the screen...

Comment: hmmm, maybe try 0.9. It shouldn't have that effect though.

Comment: Okay, it just doing contrast, i suppose. Thanks for help, though. Unfortunately, it doesn't save power. It just decrase contrast value. It has a app in Software Center. Brightness Controller. That application doing the same. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this will fix the issue, but I am finding workarounds for older versions of Ubuntu, so I'm confident these fixes have been incorporated in xorg-edgers.

**Supported Cards (using 346.16 drivers) GeForce 410M**

346 may be out of beta now, but this was still in beta as of December. If it's still beta and you want to use latest stable, replace last command with the 343 version command.

**To add the xorg-edgers ppa (terminal commands)**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-settings
```

Again, not sure if 346 still in beta. If you look and is and not comfortable with beta, the latest stable would be

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-343 nvidia-settings
```

**And if you want to remove them**

```
 sudo apt-get remove nvidia*
 sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

**remove xorg configuration:**

```
 sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

**Reinstall the Mesa package for GL:**

```
 sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

And then reboot. you would then just need to go back to 311 if you wanted.

Comment: First, thank you for your reply. When I wrote these codes to Terminal, it downloaded it, and lastly, I rebooted my PC, and I saw a NVIDIA logo. Then, I log in to my account, looked at Additional Drivers, and it using X.ORG something. And a new driver. NVIDIA Binary Driver - Version 340.76. Is it worked ? Should I switch it from X.Org Server to NVIDIA 340.76 driver ? Thanks.

Comment: First, does dimming work? Not sure why it downloaded 340.76, but yes, you can try that one if dimming not working

Comment: The xorg one is a newer version than 340, so I doubt it will work on that one if don't work on the one on now.

Comment: When on xorg one, it didn't worked. After that, changed to 340.76, and again, it didn't worked :(

Comment: Sorry. That was the only thing I could think of. Wish I could have been of more help

Comment: No, thanks for reading this and trying to help me. Again, thanks :)