# Is there an App that can make my desktop dimmer

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, brightness, backlight, xbacklight

I used an app in Windows 7, I think called dimmer to make the screen change its contrast settings so I could dim it lower than the controls of the PC defaults such as function key or the power options in control panel.

Are there any of these type apps for Ubuntu 15.04 or approved for the latest Ubuntu LTS version on a PC-laptop.

My computer has the use of function keys that change its brightness.  It uses a 0-8 step brightness scale where 0 is the least bright and 8 is the brightest.  0 is too bright for my comfort level especially at night

Following the suggestion in an answer below I added the following to etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=8bcb4169-f5ab-4ab6-b644-23e528088d41 acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and updated grub

My screen brightness did not go any dimmer than it had before.  Oddly the brightness level seems to go to level 2 brightness on a 0-8 scale every time I reboot which it did not do prior to the etc/default/grub change.  I reverted my grub file back to previous settings.

I've installed **Indicator-Brightness** but this app does not dim my desktop any further than my function keys do and there are no menus to configure it to do so.

I actively pursued other related questions to find a solution and reporting results of that action here. Its a process that takes time. To those that have provided input, Thank you for being patient.

There are many aspects to graphics, screen brightness, contrasts, color temp, gamma.

I tried

```
xbacklight -set 50
xbacklight -dec 10 and 03 etc.
```

This never increased or decreased beyond the usual 0-8 steps the PC provides i.e. no difference than current function key levels.

Interestingly a comment below my question by Serg Kolo (thanks :) led me to info on `xrandr` via the linked sources at the bottom of the information he provided concerning his script:

```
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5
```

I had no idea this was available and already installed - apparently. With the second command in terminal my screen went darker than it ever has.  I then tested:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.9
```

Which got me back to the usual lowest level.  This appears to be changing contrast levels not brightness, which is exactly what I was asking about. A simple command in terminal is as good as an App.

I have since studied [xrandr](http://www.x.org/wiki/Projects/XRandR/) so that I can get an idea of how that command works.

Perhaps someone could explain xrandr in easy terms but until then please explore the information from the link above.

### Edit Sept 16

In good faith and collaboration I decided to try the script from Serg's answer below.  Following his directions I was able to make this script work for me.  I wish I knew how the script determines what the name of my screen is for the use of `xrandr` command but the good news is it works.

Thank you Serg and all for your input

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any brightness control for desktops?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/583863/is-there-any-brightness-control-for-desktops)

Comment: Take a look at a script I wrote a year ago: http://askubuntu.com/a/589574/295286.  It's the one after "Update" part. Perhaps you may find it useful

Comment: Also, questions marked as duplicates for a reason. The type of question you ask has been asked hundreds of times on this and unix.stackexchange.com sites.  They are not intended as offence, but rather as tool to direct users to similar questions that already have possible solutions.  Additionally, scripts are one of the standard ways to troubleshooting Linux issues or creating workarounds. And a script file, made executable, is already a custom-made app.

Comment: @Serg Your link led me to something that is very close to a solution but I don't understand it. Could you please review the bottom area of my question and provide an explanation/answer.

Comment: @xtrchessreal Alright, I'll post an answer a bit later. Right now a bit busy. I'll try to make it as simple as possible

Comment: @muru I apologize if any of my words offended you. It was never my intention to do so. I am removing irrelevant comments on this question as a show of good faith. I proceeded to analyze each of the answers in the related question and actively edited information in the question with my results (still ongoing) in good faith. I am trying to participate in a collaborative way. I am editing the question further to read in a more positive, objective, and unbiased fashion.  Thank you for editing the code and outputs to read better.  That was a nice gesture in the face of apparent hostile comments. :)

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, muru Please accept my apologies for my stubborn behavior and what must have seemed inappropriate. After Serg's comments led me to Raja's information I studied xrandr at X.org and links sourced there. I agree a script is a set of steps via function calls and commands that manipulate the OS for a specified result that as a whole can be called a program or an App. In my defense I am new here, to a well constructed Linux OS, and was uninformed which led to a string of unfortunately timed events.

Comment: Jacob Vlijm, muru, @Serg, Raja It is my hope that someone can place a generally stated explanation in an answer below with sourced links and/or material of the xrandr commands use such that these scripts and their use of xrandr can be understood by the community.

Comment: Create the Dimmer.sh manually with gedit text editor and change it's permission with chmod manually.  They are nothing but simple text files

Comment: What's your username? `x`?

Comment: @A.B. Yes my username is x - Thanks for the edit, I wish I knew how to make a scroll window for code output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps exactly:

1. Open terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Create a folder for the script

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/bin
   ```
3. Open the file `~/bin/setup.sh` in `gedit`.

   ```
   gedit ~/bin/setup.sh
   ```
4. **Copy** over the code below **save** the file, **close** the editor.

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # Author: Serg Kolo
   # Date: Mon Aug 24 , 2015
   # Description: setup script for creating
   # launcher and setting up the Dimmer script

   DESKFILE="$HOME/bin/Dimmer.desktop"
   SCHEMA="com.canonical.Unity.Launcher"
   KEY="favorites"
   SCRIPTFILE="$HOME/bin/Dimmer.sh"

   createBinFolder() {
    if [ ! -e "$HOME/bin" ]; then
      mkdir "$HOME/bin"
    fi
    echo "created bin folder"
   }

   createLauncher() {
    OUTPUT="$(gsettings get $SCHEMA $KEY | awk -v file="$DESKFILE" -v sq="'"  '{ sub(/\]/,""); print  $0","sq"application://"file sq "]"  }')" ;
    gsettings set $SCHEMA $KEY "$OUTPUT" ;
    echo "Launcher for Dimmer created"
   }

   createScriptFile() {
    touch "$SCRIPTFILE"
    chmod 755 "$SCRIPTFILE"
    echo "Created script file. Please copy over the code to \"$SCRIPTFILE\""
   }

   createDeskFile() {
    printf "[Desktop Entry]\nName=Dimmer\nExec=%s\nType=Application\nTerminal=false" "$SCRIPTFILE" > "$DESKFILE"
   }

   createBinFolder
   createScriptFile
   createDeskFile
   createLauncher
   ```
5. Make the file executable and start the setup script

   ```
   chmod 755 ~/bin/setup.sh && ~/bin/setup.sh
   ```

   That script will create `bin` folder and blank `Dimmer.sh` file.
6. Edit the file `Dimmer.sh`

   ```
   gedit ~/bin/Dimmer.sh
   ```
7. **Copy** the code below, **save** and **close** the editor

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # Name: backlightscript
   # Author: Serg Kolo
   # Date: March 2 , 2015
   # Description: Simple script to change screen brightness using xrandr

   # uncomment this for debugging as needed
   # set -x

   NEWVAL=$( zenity --scale --min-value=0 --max-value=7 --text="Enter number between 0 and 7" ) && brightness=$(($NEWVAL+2))

   if [ "$NEWVAL" != "" ]; then
       xrandr --output "$( xrandr | awk '$2=="connected" {print $1}')" --brightness 0.$brightness
   fi
   ```

Now you should be able to double click on the launcher and get that dimmer app working.

Comment: Where is `SCHEMA` and `KEY` defined?

Comment: Top of the script , bellow the #! Line

Comment: Arg, I'm blind =\

Comment: Serg I need your help, I seem to have run into a problem while trying to build the script, I cannot find the `dimmer.sh` file to copy the rest of the script into. Please see my new entry at the bottom of my question for details.  Thank you for your help

Comment: In the `setup.sh` file, there is no call to the `createBinFolder` function.  Add it above the `createScriptFile` function call.

Comment: @Terrance I was able to build the script with revised instructions. I don't know scripting at all but perhaps your suggestion was the missing piece before - Thanks

Comment: @xtrchessreal You're very welcome!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the file /etc/default/grub and change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot, you should have the ability to lower the screen backlight to completely black.

Comment: To backup grub first is this the correct line: 'sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak' and if I had a boot fail for any reason can I revert  via recovery mode terminal and just reverse the order of that line like: 'sudo cp /etc/default/grub.bak /etc/default/grub'  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @xtrchessreal if GRUB is broken, can you still enter Recovery Mode? I think you'd have to use a liveUSB/CD, which you could use to just rebuild GRUB.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Thanks for your input.  GRUB is not broken and my PC boots without any fatal issues.