# Turn off a screen in terminal

Tags: command-line, multiple-monitors, display

Hoy.

I have a multi monitor setup and when watching movies I'd like to turn off or black out the other screens.

I've tried

```
xset -display :0 dpms force off
```

and

```
xset -display :0.0 dpms force off
```

however it turns all the screens off. `echo $DISPLAY` prints `:0`  .

Does anyone know some magic?

Comment: Answer already posted, please upvote it if works for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/551109/how-to-black-out-screen-when-watching-video-playing-game-on-other-screen

Comment: I just used that linked answer myself but assigned keyboard shortcuts <super>+B to blank the screen and <super>+U to unblank the screen. +1 to your great question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how did you setup your monitors but you can use xrandr to turn off an screen like this:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --off
```

which turns off the monitor connected to VGA1. you can change VGA1 to eDP, HDMI, etc.

Comment: It's functional but possibly that you cannot make your monitor back